# Passing custom component props into navigator route as a parametr

Tags: javascript, react-native

I fetch categories from API and I have tried to pass categories via screenProps as  a parametr of a route in the stack navigator . My categories are in array . That's why I assigned it 0 index of array . But It didn't work . it gives me undefined . I manually tried it with assigning catId = 1 and title = 'Filmler' . It works very well. What is the right way  ?

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    cat_list: [],
      error : null,

  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    try {
      const url="https://bilettm.com/api/v1/categories";
      const catsApiCall = await fetch(url);
      const categories = await catsApiCall.json();
      this.setState({cat_list:categories,error:null})
    }catch (err) {
      console.log("Error fetching data-----------", err);
      this.setState({error:err})
    }
  }

  render() {
    // console.warn(this.state.cat_list);

    return (
    <View style={{flex:1,}}>
      <NavigationDrawer screenProps = {this.state.cat_list}/>

    </View>
    );
  }
}



const app = createStackNavigator({
       FromMainScreenToSubCats:{
                    screen:FromMainScreenToSubCats,
                    params: { catId:this.props.screenProps.cats[0].id , title:this.props.screenProps.cats[0].title_tk }
           },
            MainScreeen:{
                screen:MainScreen
            },

            Orders:{
                screen:OrdersScreen
            },
            EventDetail:{
                screen:EventDetailScreen
            },
            Seats:{
                screen:SeatsScreen
            },
            ReviewPay:{
                screen:ReviewPay
            },
            EventsScreen:{
                screen:EventsScreen
            },

            SeatsScreen2:{
                screen:SeatsScreen2
            },
            clientinfo:{
                screen:clientinfo
            },
            clientBankAccountInfo:{
                screen:clientBankAccountInfo
            },
            PaymentScreenViaWebView:{
                screen:PaymentScreenViaWebView
            },
            eventDetailScreenTest:{
                screen:eventDetailScreenTest
            }
            ,


        }
        ,{
    headerMode:false,
    }

        )


export default createAppContainer(app);
```